# Delete @ObservedRealmObject in SwiftUI View

Tags: swift, swiftui, realm

I am using Realm to persist a data on the device.

**Question**: What is the correct implementation to delete an object view using  `@ObservedRealmObject` property?

Here is a simplified implementation of the view:

```
import RealmSwift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedResults(Item.self) var items

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    NavigationLink(destination: ItemDetailView(item: item)) {
                        Text(item.name)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ItemDetailView: View {
    @ObservedRealmObject var item: Item

    var body: some View {
        Text(item.name)
            .onTapGesture {
                let realm = Realm()

                try! realm.write {
                    realm.delete(item)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

**Expectation**: Item is deleted and screen navigates back to list

**Result**: The item is being deleted, however, the exception below is being thrown:

```
This method may only be called on RLMArray instances retrieved from an RLMRealm
```

I have tried to delete `@ObservedRealmObject` which will give an expected result, however I will be losing a property which allows the `ItemDetailView` to "know" when the object has changed regardless of where that change happened.

Comment: Are you intentionally passing a Class to ItemDetailView? `ItemDetailView(item: Item))` (note the upper case). I would think you would want to pass `item` which is a specific Item object. The error is because you're attempting to delete a Class `Item` instead of an class object `item` (I think) and `Item` was not retrieved from Realm

Comment: @Jay that's just a typo, I am passing an `item`. But that `item` is also a class since realm objects are live objects (reference type)

Comment: `@ObservedRealmObjects` are frozen - they need to be thawed of you want to modify them within a write.

Answer (score 3):

@ObservedRealmObjects are frozen - they need to be thawed of you want to modify them within a write.

Thawing an item also thaws the Realm it belongs to so protect your code by ensuring it's a valid object before deleting

Something along these lines is good practice

```
let thawedItem = item.thaw()

if thawedItem.invalidated == false { //ensure it's a valid item

   let thawedRealm = thawedItem!.realm! //get the realm it belongs to

   try! thawedRealm.write {
      thawedRealm.delete(thawedItem)
   }
}
```

From the [SwiftUI Quickstart guide](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/swift/swiftui/)

> @ObservedRealmObject is a frozen object. If you want to modify the
> properties of an @ObservedRealmObject directly in a write transaction,
> you must .thaw() it first.

and then see how to [Modify a Frozen Object](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/swift/advanced-guides/threading/#modify-a-frozen-object)